# Decoration marks not working with "in" and "out" attributes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-decorations

I am using this Ti*k*Z code :

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, positioning}
\tikzset{
    mdot/.style={
        shorten >=#1,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark={
                at position 1
                with {
                    \node [circle,  thin, draw=blue, fill=white, inner sep=#1,radius=#1] at (0,0) {}; 
                }
            }
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    },
    mdot/.default=1pt
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}    
    \node [draw] (n1) {configuration files};
    \node [draw,right=1cm of n1] (n2) {binaries};
    \draw [draw=gray!50,mdot] (n1) to (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

This work as expected, with a small circle at the end of the line from n1 to n2.

[image]

but if I add the "out" and "in" attributes, like this

```tex
\draw [draw=gray!50,mdot,out=0,in=90] (n1) to (n2);
```

then the small circle disappears.
[image]

I don't know why the circle disappears?

Comment: `at position .99 with={...}` works, hence the cause seems to be some rounding error(s).

Comment: If mar is at end of line, why you use `decorations.markings`? Does simple `\draw[-{Cricle[<size>]}]` is not sufficient (with `arrows.meta` library)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, for arrow with arrowhead on the end of line is use of `decorations.markings` "overkill" solution. It can be simple achieved for example by `\draw [gray,-{Circle[open,blue]}] (n1) to (n2);`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw] (n1) {configuration files};
    \node [draw,right=of n1] (n2) {binaries};
    \draw [gray,-{Circle[open,blue]}] (n1) to (n2);
    \draw [gray!50,-{Circle[open,blue]}] (n1) to[out=0,in=90] (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]